# TS1127: Invalid character on razor pages while passing Guid to js method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm getting the following error in the code below, my intention is to pass a Guid Id to a javascript method.  I get error ts1127 invalid character for back slash

```
<td>@category.Name</td>
<td id="bootstrap-overrides"> <button type="button" onclick="deleteIncidentCategory( \'' + @category.Id + '\' );" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Delete</button></td>
<td id="bootstrap-overrides"> <button type="button" onclick='Jump(\"@category.Id\");' class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Delete</button></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it like this:

```
<button onclick="Jump('@category.Id');" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Hi @mj1313 it did work! thanks for your help mate

Comment: Hi @MiladIld , if this reply is helpful to you, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), thanks!

Comment: Just remove the semicolon after the parenthesis